# Is there a way to scan through my assets folder?

Tags: android, assets

Android gives you access to the assets folder (in which i have my fonts, for example) by way of `getAssets()`.  However, I'm not seeing any way to then introspect what's in there, and get a dynamic list of the assets.

Is this not possible? 
And if not, is there an alternate location to keep things such as fonts, so that I can pull a dynamic list of what's in there at run-time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `AssetManager.list(String path)` method which returns all files at the specified path.

Comment: ah! lovely... that's precisely what I was looking for.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel  IMHO, AssetManager sucks.  It's slow, and has no way to recurse the path.  I wrote a method to use .list recursively but it's very slow.  If you would like more details, let me know.

Comment: I appreciate the heads up. Speed isn't really an issue in this case for me.